# Split String Every 2 Character into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with my code. I have a series of string. For example I made this:

```
var a = 12345678
```

I want to split these string into an array, so that it will produce something like this:

```
[12,23,34,45,56,67,78]
```

I already tried this code:

```
var newNum = a.toString().match(/.{1,2}/g)
```

and it returns this result instead of the result I wanted

```
[12,34,56,78]
```

Are there any solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with a simple `for` loop or  array processing method. You can't do this with regex alone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```js
var a = 12345678;
a= a.toString();
var arr=[];
for (var i =0; i<a.length-1; i++) {
 arr.push(Number(a[i]+''+a[i+1]));
}

console.log(arr);
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks Nick Parsons, I used Number() function.

Comment: You can add you code in [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), that makes answer more interactive, +1 for old for loop

Comment: Code Maniac, yes added the code snippet. thank you!

Answer (score 7):

#### Updated answer to address the question body

```js
'1234567'.split('').map((e,i,a) => a[i] + (a[i+1] ?? '')).slice(0,-1);
// Array(6) [ "12", "23", "34", "45", "56", "67" ]
```

#### Original answer

Edit: I see now this doesn't answer the problem described in the question body. I'll leave it though, as the problem it solves may well be described by the question title.

---

Shortest way:

```js
'abcdefg'.split(/(..)/g).filter(s => s);
// Array(4) [ "ab", "cd", "ef", "g" ]
```

Explanation: `split(/(..)/g)` splits the string every two characters (kinda), from what I understand the captured group of any two characters `(..)` acts as a lookahead here (for reasons unbeknownst to me; if anyone has an explanation, contribution to this answer is welcome). This results in `Array(7) [ "", "ab", "", "cd", "", "ef", "g" ]` so all that's left to do is weed out the empty substrings with `filter(s => s)`.

Comment: `'abcdefg'.match(/(..)/g)` is an even shorter version, though is not what Mohammand asked for.

Comment: @luvejo Fair point. I updated the answer, adding a functional approach to the problem described in the question body.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like this:

```js
let str = "12345678",
    length = str.length - 1,
    output = Array.from({ length }, (_,i) => +str.slice(i, i+2))

console.log(output)
```

Here's a generic solution for getting varying size of chunks:

```js
function getChunks(number, size) {
  let str = number.toString(),
      length = str.length - size + 1;
      
  return Array.from({ length }, (_,i) => +str.slice(i, i + size))
}

console.log(getChunks(12345, 3))
console.log(getChunks(12345678, 2))
```

Comment: works, but can you please explain this
`Array.from({ length }, (_,i) => +str.slice(i, i+2))`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using `Array.reduce` :

- Firstly, convert the number into a string and then split it into an array
- Secondly, apply reduce on the resulting array, then append current element `ele` with the next element only if the next element exists.
- Lastly, after the append is done with the current and next element convert it back to a number by prefixing it with an arithmetic operator `+` and then add it to the accumulator array.

```js
var a = 12345678;

const result = a.toString().split("").reduce((acc, ele, idx, arr) => {
  return arr[idx + 1] ? acc.concat(+(ele + arr[idx + 1])) : acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
console.assert(result, [12,23,34,45,56,67,78]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using `reduce`

```
var a = 12345678
a.toString()
 .split('')
 .reduce((c,x,i,A)=>i>0?c.concat([A[i-1]+A[i]]):c,[])
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is start with the first two digits (12) and then add eleven until you have an array that ends with the last digit of the input string (8).

```js
let str = `12345678`;

const eleven = string => {
  let result = [];
  let singles = string.split('');
  let first = Number(singles.splice(0, 2).join(''));
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length-1; i++) {
    let next = 11 * i;
    result.push(first+next);
  }
  return result;
}
    
console.log(eleven(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 12345678;
console.log(
  String(a)
    .split("")
    .map((value, index, array) => [value, array[index + 1]].join(''))
    .map(item => Number(item))
);

output  - [ 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 8 ]
```

explanation

- String(a) - convert your number value 'a' into string, to prepare for operations
- split("") - convert string value into array
- > .map((value, index, array) => [value, array[index + 1]] ...

for every item from array, take current value and next value, and put them into array cell

- .join('')) - then create string from this array value like this [ '1', '2' ] => ['12']
- .map(item => Number(item)) - at the end, convert every array item into number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive approach. Here I used an auxiliary function to perform the recursion, and the main function to convert the number to a string.

See example below:

```js
const arr = 12345678;

const group = a => group_aux(`${a}`);
const group_aux = ([f, s, ...r]) =>
  !s ? [] : [+(f+s), ...group_aux([s, ...r])];

console.log(group(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

My requirement is to convert a MD5 string (with length: 32) to a Uint8Array (with length: 16) as the key of AES algorithm. Reference from the post above, thanks.

```js
var a = 'a12ab32fd78a89efa12ab32fd78a89ef';
var arr=[];
for (var i =0; i<a.length-1; i+=2) {
 arr.push(parseInt(a[i]+''+a[i+1], 16));
}

console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr);
console.log(new Uint8Array(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter, a more legible solution is:

```js
let even = '12345678'.match(/(..)/g)
let odd = '2345678'.match(/(..)/g)
let result = [...even, ...odd]
```

If order does matter, just use `.sort()`:

```js
result.sort()
```